Contract.functions "not found" in Web3.py
Testing this python code on UBUNTU :
import requests
import json
from eth_account import Account
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
 
caller = "0xb9****f832860DBD"
private_key = "1d7bb4b13a48b54********5336726f"
 
url = 'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/8afa5e30c******14b5d'
 
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(url))
#nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(caller)
 
abi= '[{"constant": false,"inputs": [{"***************************": [{"name": "","type": "bool"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"},{"constant": true,"inputs": [],"name": "Owner","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "address"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"}]'
  
nonce=w3.eth.get_transaction_count(caller)
chainId = w3.eth.chain_id
 
contract_address = "0x*******9B78"
 
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

result = contract.functions.CheckMoneyOnTheContract({"chainId": chainId, "from": caller, "nonce": nonce })

 

When I try to continue my editor doesn'found contract.functions .....
Trace expl 1
web3.exceptions.Web3ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name CheckMoneyOnTheContract, positional arguments with type(s) dict and keyword arguments with type(s) {}.
Found 1 function(s) with the name CheckMoneyOnTheContract: ['CheckMoneyOnTheContract()']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.
has context menu
(For me the abi is correct)
Trace expl 2
Web3 version:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/**************epolia.py", line 7, in 
print(Web3.version)
AttributeError: type object 'Web3' has no attribute 'version'
ABI portion:
{ "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "CheckMoneyOnTheContract", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }
Can somebody tell me my ??

Which version of web3.py are you using ?

In the editor, it usually doesn't find and recommend the available functions in the instance. However, when you execute it, it would work if you're calling an existing function in the ABI.

web3.version  -> not found .... more and more strange ....

Please edit the question and include the full Python traceback in the question

Trace included ... Thanks for your time.

Can you please add the ABI portion for your CheckMoneyOnTheContract() function, as well as the line where you’re calling this function?

ABI section and call added.

I managed to fix the problem. The issue came mainly from the fact that the required number of arguments were not send to the smart contract function.
My editor still doesn't found contract.functions .... but is not an issue, it works.
Still doesn't know how to print the Web3 library version ....
Below is an example of a working example using one smart contract function with one string parameter.
param_value = "TestHash"  

transaction = {
    'to': contract_address,
    'from': caller,
    'gas': 200000, 
    'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),  
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(caller), 
    'data': contract.encodeABI(fn_name='setHash', args=[param_value]),  
}
 
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
 
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
 
w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash) 


You can see the version installed with web3.__version__.

In the python code ? like :
print(web3.version)

On my side it's not working : No attribute 'version'

That's working for me with the current stable version 6.17.2. I'm not sure at what point it was added.
>>> import web3
>>> print(web3.__version__)
6.17.2

